# Laravel : whereNull for pivot

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, relationship

I have an orders (Order Model) table related to books (Book Model) via `order_items` pivot table :

```
 public function books()
  {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Book', 'order_item')

 ->withPivot(['quantity', 'presenter_id', 'price', 'portion', 'settlement_id']);
 }
```

I need to filter results that their `presenter_id` is null in pivot table(order_items).
but there is no method like `wherePivotNull` . i also tried below solution([reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/query-where-pivot-not-null/replies/116347)) but no chance :

```
 public function books()
  {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Book', 'order_item')

 ->withPivot(['quantity', 'presenter_id', 'price', 'portion',    'settlement_id'])

  ->getQuery()->whereNull('order_items.presenter_id')->get();
 }
```

it throw this exception :

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\pnu\resources\views\orders\table.blade.php) (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\pnu\resources\views\orders\table.blade.php)

Comment: You have a typo in your whereNull: "presneter_id".

Comment: thanks , modified. of course the issue is not related to that

Comment: Was worth a shot. :) Hope you find the error.

Comment: Have you tried without the `->get()` at the end or using the `wherePivot()` method?

Comment: Yes.wherePivot doesnt accept anonymous function like what we can do with query builder , it only accept `column`,`operator`,`value` triple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `whereNull()` directly on the relationship, but you will need to make sure to qualify the field names with the name of the pivot table.

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Book', 'order_item')
        ->whereNull('order_items.presenter_id')
        ->withPivot(['quantity', 'presenter_id', 'price', 'portion', 'settlement_id']);
}
```

When you call `whereNull()` on the relationship, internally it will call `whereNull()` on the underlying query builder, and then return the relationship object. In the example you provided, you called `whereNull()` on the query builder directly (by calling `getQuery()` first), which will return the query builder object, which will throw an exception.

Comment: This one does not affect *$this->pivotWheres[]* on relations's model, while all *wherePivot\**-methods does.